# Installing OpenCV in Raspberry Pi error while doing make

Tags: python, c++, opencv, numpy

I am getting the following errors after doing running 'make' command.

```
[  0%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matmul.o
c++: error: -pg and -fomit-frame-pointer are incompatible
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matmul.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am following the tutorial on http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/ link.

Following were missing when i did cmake before doing make:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 46 (406)
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' not found
-- checking for module 'libswscale'
--   package 'libswscale' not found
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
--     Use NumPy headers from: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/numpy/core/include
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sphinx
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY) (Required is at least version "4.0")
-- Parsing 'cvconfig.h.cmake'
```

Can somebody please explain what is happening and what is the solution to it ? I am new to both OpenCV and R-Pi.

Comment: I'm guessing your missing 'Jasper' and 'sphinx' packages/modules?

Comment: You have apparently configured your OpenCV build to use/include CUDA (and you haven't installed it), I don't think you want to do that in a R-Pi environment. Did you use the exact OpenCV version indicated in that tutorial? (ie. `wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1a.tar.bz2` )

Comment: Yes I am using the exact OpenCV version and following the link as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Following the link you refer "as is" will have solved the issue.

Some essential packages are missing and hence the error.

Install by entering the following commands before compiling OpenCV. You must have an active net connection!

> sudo apt-get -y install build-essential cmake cmake-qt-gui pkg-config
>   libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libpng++-dev libpng3 libpnglite-dev zlib1g-dbg
>   zlib1g zlib1g-dev pngtools libtiff4-dev libtiff4 libtiffxx0c2
>   libtiff-tools
>
> sudo apt-get -y install libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev
>   libjpeg8-dbg libjpeg-progs ffmpeg libavcodec-dev libavcodec53
>   libavformat53 libavformat-dev libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg
>   libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libxine1-ffmpeg libxine-dev
>   libxine1-bin libunicap2 libunicap2-dev libdc1394-22-dev libdc1394-22
>   libdc1394-utils swig libv4l-0 libv4l-dev python-numpy libpython2.6
>   python-dev python2.6-dev libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config